Problem with writing to USB devices
Writing to a USB flash drive is very, very fast. Theoretically it shows 1.5-1.7 GB/s, but at 100% it stops without finishing.
I tried blocking the UAS for the device by adding a file in /etc/modprobe.d/ with options usb-storage quirks=<VendorID>:<ProductID>:u but this method does not work for some reason. Later I created a file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-disable-uas.rules with ACTION==“add”, SUBSYSTEM==“usb”, ATTR{idVendor}==“VendorID”, ATTR{idProduct}==“ProductID”, TEST==“current”, ATTR{authorized}=“0”, equally this method does not work. I don't know why. Finally, I created a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-uas.conf file with the content blacklist uas, this method actually blocked the UAS. Unfortunately, the copying continued in the same way, very fast, and without end.
I finally came across a similar problem described on Askubuntu:
echo vm.dirty_bytes=15000000 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p

Copying looks more real, speeds up to 50 MB/s, ends when it reaches 100%.
I've read a bit and I see that the vm.dirty_bytes, vm.dirty_ratio and vm.dirty_background_ratio settings can help, but they affect all processes writing to the system. That is, my setting (dirty_bytes=15000000) affects, for example, how I write to the fast internal SSD. In making the USB drive responsive, I would have to lower these settings, so that the internal writing processes would run smoothly, preferably leaving the system default settings.
Is there an optimal solution to this problem?
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.10
KDE Plasma Version: 6.1.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.6.0
Qt Version: 6.6.2
Kernel Version: 6.11.0-9-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 12 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i5-11600 @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Graphics
Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
Product Name: MS-7D18
System Version: 1.0


https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2089058

https://gitlab.manjaro.org/fhdk/udev-usb-sync
